# Answering yes/no a question with 会。

Tags: grammar

Can you answer to a question with only the verb of the question?. Is it right if you put an aclaration afterwards?

This is the example.

A- 她会按医生的话去做吗？

B- 会，他决定按医生的话去做。

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes/no can usually be expressed simply by the verb as you have noticed.

> 是不是....
>   是

> 能不能....
>   能

Many learners however like to reply awkwardly with words like 对, if you reply in this manner it would sound much more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said 他會的

If you want to emphasize, you can always add 我會盯著他

Answer (score 1):

> Can you answer to a question with only the verb of the question?

Yes, we can.  The verb is taken as the shorthand of the sentence (with  rest part omitted). As in your example:

> A- 她会按医生的话去做吗？
>
> B- 会，他决定按医生的话去做。

And you can emphasize the point by repeating the full version.  In this case, it's 她会按医生的话去做.

So, the normal dialogue would be most likely to be:

> A- 她会按医生的话去做吗？
>
> B- 会，他**会**按医生的话去做

Another example:

> A: 你愿意嫁给我吗？
>
> B: 愿意，(我愿意)，我愿意嫁给你。

Answer (score 0):

The example is totally correct and native.